# Using copy action cards to copy actions

Tags: mariposas

In Mariposas, there are two different types of card that copy a previously played card.

One copies a card you have previously played, the other copies an card an opponent has previously played.

Can I chain these together? Can I use a copy a card I previously played to copy the "copy an opponent's card" I used earlier to get access to my opponents cards again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

The designer Elizabeth Hargrave answers on [this BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2493681/article/35697670#35697670) forum post a question if a player can copy an opponents card that we results in copying on there own back.   To which she replied.

> LOL sure, go for it.

This would suggest that any kind of chaining of cards, including the example in your question, is a legal play.